# How to reset bash bindings?

Tags: bash, bashrc

I wanted to create bash binding so that <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>backspace</kbd> deletes word in terminal. But I somehow ended up screwing up my backspace and now it doesn't work, it outputs character.
I know I can list all binding with `bind -P` but can't delete them or find where file with bindings is located.
I have `.inputrc` but its empty.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `bind -r "key"` to remove the binding. For example if you have yank bound to `"\C-y"` issuing `bind -r "\C-y"` will remove that binding (in the current shell). To reset all key bindings to default use `set -o emacs` or `set -o vi`.

Comment: use 'bind -r <keycode>' if you can't type the key. https://keycode.info/

Comment: ..and use * in place of a single key if you can't even type a key needed to edit .bashrc or type the above command, ie if you bound any of the keys b,i,n,d,-,r,#s by accident